# How to make bootstrap 4 child element display block inside row class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I tried to make child div as display block using d-block class but it's not working bootstrap 4 row class will take display flex, I tried to achieve through clearfix but no result please anyone help me on this.
Please anyone help me on this

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ul</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-block p-0">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need `display:block`?

Comment: Sir, I need to make child row class as block

Comment: That does not answer the question. Why???

Comment: can u plz add this in codepen? By default, display:block !important will work as per bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap 4's `.row` class has following css:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

So, element with `row` class becomes `flex-container` and all immediate children of this container becomes `flex-item` or `flex-child`. so in your code the nested `row` becomes `flex-child` and by default for `display: flex;` the `flex-direction` property is set to `row` which makes all flex children sit next to each other on same row and their content decides there width.  Here `flex-wrap: wrap;` makes children wrap to next line if the `flex-container` doesn't have enough space.

So by adding `d-block` class if you were trying to make it take up full width, it will not as it is `flex-child`. To make it take up full available width you can use bootstrap's sizing class `w-100` to force it to take up full available width instead of `d-block`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need it full width. You can set flex column in row parent by add `flex-column` class

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-column">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ul</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-block p-0">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```